# Gram-Schmidt orthonormal basis

Tags: orthogonality, orthonormal, gram-schmidt

**Given:** I am given four different signals

\begin{align}
   s_0(t) = 
   \begin{cases}
      2, \ \ \ \ 0 < t \leq 1 \\
      -2, \ 1 < t \leq 2 \\
      2, \ \ \ \ 2 < t \leq 3 \\
   \end{cases}
   , \ \ \ s_2(t) =
   \begin{cases}
      1, \ \ \ \ 0 < t \leq 1 \\
      -2, \ 1 < t \leq 2 \\
   \end{cases}
\end{align}
\begin{align}
   s_1(t) =
   \begin{cases}
      -1, \ 0 < t \leq 1 \\
      3, \ \ \ \ 1 < t \leq 2 \\
      1, \ \ \ \ 2 < t \leq 3
   \end{cases}
   ,\ \ \ s_3(t) =
   \begin{cases}
      -1, \ 0 < t \leq 2 \\
      -3, \ 2 < t \leq 3      
   \end{cases}
\end{align}

**Question:** I want to find the orthonormal basis functions using Gram-Schmidt procedure.

**Solution:** I pretty much know how the Gram-Schmidt algorithm works, but I am note sure how to do the calculations. If I let $s_1$ and $s_2$ form a basis I can calculate the norm as

\begin{align}
   e_1(t) = \frac{s_1}{\langle s_1,s_1 \rangle} = \frac{s_1}{\int_0^{\infty}s_1^2dt}
\end{align}
But what i wonder here is what is the integral of $s_1^2$ ?

For $e_2(t)$ we have

\begin{align}
   e_2(t) = \frac{s_2}{\langle s_2,s_2 \rangle} = \frac{s_2}{\int_0^{\infty}s_2^2dt}
\end{align}

Also here I don't know how to calculate the integral of $s_2^2$?
So, basically I know the procedure but lack knowledge how to calculate integrals of functions that are not continuous. Is there somebody who can give me a hint? The rest should be straightforward.

Comment: Hint. These functions are piecewise continuous, so you can compute the integrals by adding up the areas for each piece.Those areas will be rectangles, so you don't really need to "integrate". Draw pictures.

Comment: Is this a telecommunications course hw? Anyway, regarding the integrals, take squares of your piecewise constant signals and then calculate areas of the rectangles above t axis. Id est: $s_1$'s norm is $1^2*1+3^2*1+1^2*1=11$. Other than that start with $e_1$ but note that $s_1$ and $s_2$ are not orthogonal, their inner product is -7 I guess.

Comment: Thank for the comments, they really helped me

Comment: Okey, I notice I forgot that $s_0$, and not $s_1$ is my first signal. So will have 

\begin{align}
   e_1(t) = \frac{s_0}{\langle s_1, s_1 \rangle} = \frac{s_1}{\int_0^3s_1^2dt} = \frac{s_1}{2^2*1 + 2^2*1 + 2^2*1} = \frac{s_1}{12}
\end{align}

but I think this is the wrong way to go, I used a solution from another exercise for approaching this one. But here neither signal is orthogonal to another, so it´s not the same case. Instead i posted an answer with a vector approach. But thanks for the comment, it lead me to the correct answer.

Answer (score 0):

It is easier to do it expressing the signals as vectors

\begin{align}
   \vec{s_0} = 
   \begin{bmatrix}
      2 \\
      -2 \\
      2 \\
   \end{bmatrix}
   , \ \ \ \vec{s_2} =
   \begin{bmatrix}
      1 \\
      -2 \\
      0
   \end{bmatrix}
\end{align}
\begin{align}
   \vec{s_1} =
   \begin{bmatrix}
      -1 \\
      3 \\
      1 
   \end{bmatrix}
   ,\ \ \ \vec{s_3} =
   \begin{bmatrix}
      -1 \\
      -1 \\
      -3      
   \end{bmatrix}
\end{align}

Now, using Gram-Schmidt procedure we have

\begin{align}
   \vec{u_0} = \vec{s_0} = 
   \begin{bmatrix}
      2 \\
      -2 \\
      2
   \end{bmatrix} 
\end{align}

and

\begin{align}
   \vec{u_1} = \vec{s_1} - \frac{\vec{u_0}\cdot\vec{s_1}}{\vec{u_0}\cdot\vec{u_0}}\vec{u_0} = 
   \begin{bmatrix}
      -1 \\
      3 \\
      1
   \end{bmatrix}
   +
   \begin{bmatrix}
      1 \\
      -1 \\
      1
   \end{bmatrix}
   =
   \begin{bmatrix}
      0 \\
      2 \\
      2
   \end{bmatrix}
\end{align}

next, we have

\begin{align}
   \vec{u_2} = \vec{s_2} - \frac{\vec{u_0}\cdot\vec{s_2}}{\vec{u_0}\cdot\vec{u_0}}\vec{u_0} - \frac{\vec{u_1}\cdot\vec{s_2}}{\vec{u_1}\cdot\vec{u_1}}\vec{u_1}  = 
   \begin{bmatrix}
      1 \\
      -2 \\
      0
   \end{bmatrix}
   -
   \begin{bmatrix}
      1 \\
      -1 \\
      1
   \end{bmatrix}
   +
   \begin{bmatrix}
      0 \\
      1 \\
      1
   \end{bmatrix}
   =
   \begin{bmatrix}
      0 \\
      0 \\
      0
   \end{bmatrix}
\end{align}
Then {$v_1,v_2$} is a orthogonal basis for W. Normalizing gives
\begin{align}
   \vec{v1} = \frac{1}{}
\end{align}